# How to change constants with enum types?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I am working on `ASP.NET MVC 4` application even though for this exact problem I think it's irrelevant. I am using `EF 5` with `Code First` and I have entity `Menu` where a menu can be one of four different types. In my entity the type of the menu is declared as

```
public class Menu
{
    //other properties
    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

and I have declared the different types as constants:

```
public static class MenuType
{
    public const int Report = 10;
    public const int Contract = 20;
    public const int Taxes = 30;
    public const int Interests = 40;
}
```

So if I want to get all Menus from `Contract` type I have this:

```
unitOfWork.MenuRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.Type == MenuType.Contract).ToList();
```

even though it's working OK I want to change this with enum values, I've tried this:

```
public static class MenuType
{
    public static enum Types
    { 
        Report = 10,
        Contract = 20,
        Taxes = 30,
        Interests = 40
    }
}
```

But then to retrieve the same records from above my code is:

```
unitOfWork.MenuRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.Type == (int)(MenuType.Types.Contract)).ToList();
```

a lot more unreadable and more to write as well. I've seen `enums` to be used in a way similar to the way I use the constants. I'm not sure, maybe I have to implement additional method.

However how I can change the constants with `enum` values without making the queries more unreadable? Maybe some additional method like `MenuTypeValue("Contract")`...

Comment: If that is anm LINQ source (IQueryable-of-T), then making it "more readable" will almost certainly break the LINQ provider. Dies EF still not support enum members directly? That sounds... Poor.

Comment: It supports. But I don't have time to expect exactly how to use it with `Code First` it would be more than enough to do it from inside the application itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to change the type of the property on the `Menu` class to match the new enum you declared

```
public class Menu
{
    //other properties
    public Types Type { get; set; }
}
```

This way you will be comparing an enum to an enum and your code will become nice and clear again.

If you cannot do that, you will be probably better off with sticking to `int` constants or you will need to cast between `int` and the enum type all the time.

Comment: Well I hoped for easier solution, changing the type of `Type` is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Change type of property "Type" in your model to enum. EF5 smart enough to internally convert it to int.

Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is make it more readable, why not move the logic into the repository class.

So you could make a call:

```
unitOfWork.MenuRepository.GetAll(MenuType.Type.Contract);
```

Then in your repository just have a method such as:

```
List<...> GetAll(MenuType.Type type = null) { ... }
```

So now you can still call GetAll without the type as it's an optional param but in that method you can work out what you need to be returning. Your calls will look cleaner then.

Comment: Yeah, changing the repository seems like promising idea, but I have to see if I won't break something, hmm..